# Crystal Report image is not getting updated?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, report

I am generating a crystal report with an image in it. After first generation of report I close the report viewer and changed the url of the image inside the dataset which was used to fill the report data.

But the change is not reflecting as I am regenerating the report and showing it on the report viewer.

I have refreshed the report and report viewer.
Also clear the cache by setting the viewer ReportSource as null. But previous image was still their unchanged.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When designing the report, do you have "Save Data in the Report" option unchecked?

Comment: From where I will get this option ?

Comment: When designing the crystal report, theere should be a tab called "Main Report Preview". Click that. Then in the upper left corner you should see a checkbox called "Save Data in the Report". Uncheck this.

Comment: ok, thanks @Douglas, but I have done it using the byte[] (image type). Thank you anyways. And solution is present everywhere hence I am not repeating it.back here.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue also. The following fixed the issue for me:

```
rpt.SetDataSource(datasource);
rpt.Refresh();
```