# Image in crystal report vs 2015

Tags: crystal-reports

I work in crystal report in vs 2015 and i have url images field in databas i show this image in crystal report using graphic location formula

but when i update image in database not show in crystal report i must restart application to show the image

I work in crystal report in vs 2015 and i have url images field in databas i show this image in crystal report using graphic location formula

but when i update image in database not show in crystal report i must restart application to show the image

please help me to solve this problem

exactly problem at [Crystal Report image is not getting updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27966781/crystal-report-image-is-not-getting-updated)